# Hindi/English keyboard for input text for specific application

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an application which have text field to enter text from users. I need to provide users options to select a language(Hindi/English/Marathi) to enter their text in their language.
I have downloaded Hindi keyboard but every time I have to change settings. I want when user get out of application they get their default keyboard (Keyboard should be application specific). I checked custom keyboard but creating keyboard is headache. Is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Go to play store and install "Go Keyboard" then "Hindi for Go Keyboard" and then you need to make it your default Keyboard.

That's all settings you need!, you won't need to change settings every time as there is a button ON-THE-KEYBOARD(No Settings!!) to switch from English to Hindi and from Hindi back to English. It saves a lot of time and serves it's purpose well!!